# sql data reader showing one record less than sql query output

Tags: asp.net

i have made a simple stored procedure to select all records where name will be like '%search text%'. the the stored procedure is returning correct results. But when i tried to show these result set into gridview using sqldatareader, it populate one record less. Help Pls.

Comment: Give us your code.  It's a bug in your code, not a design error, so we can't tell you how to fix it other than "find the bug" if you don't give us the code.

Comment: Are you taking a true count from both results?  Or are you taking the last index?  If it's a zero based index, this could represent the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from yourtable where yourcol like @parm" );
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parm", searchText);

conn.Open();
command.Connection = conn;
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
GridView1.DataSource = reader;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

if you're looping through the SqlDataReader, it's zero based.